# Modify MP3 File

Tags: php, file, mp3

I have an MP3 file uploader. I want to add an additional audio track to the file upon upload via PHP. Is that possible?

Comment: When you say additional audio track, Do you mean you want a track to play alongside it, or do you want a little something added to the end?

Comment: I want something to play simultaneously. Moreover, I want this other track to be repeated periodically in the resulting file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I say "Yes, it's possible".

The following seems to make it seem almost trivial: "[How to Merge / Concatenate MP3s with PHP](http://www.theblog.ca/merge-mp3s-php)"

Answer (score 0):

(based on comments)

It's not possible, well not directly possible. Not with just PHP.

With PHP you could break up a Mp3 and insert your own little snippet into pauses, but it probably won't sound very good, and if I am thinking correctly will result in lowered audio quality.

To really achieve what you want you would need something inbetween to process the Mp3 files. More than likely it would be a Unix shell script attached to some program or library that can do this, executed by PHP.